# Google Analytics Goal Conversion Scope

Tags: google-analytics

Struggling to find the answer to this query, but is a google analytics goal conversion (URL destination) scope set at hit, session or user?

i.e. if it was at user scope and a user hit that same URL say 5 times, would the goal conversion be 5 for the user or 1?

Answer (score 1):

Goals are incremented once per session per goal per user.

If your user hit the same url 5 times during the same session, then it will show as 1 when you report on the user.

If your user hit the same url 5 times during different sessions, then it will show as 5 when you report on the user.